# Subscribing to route params and data in Angular 2

Tags: angular

My form needs to access route params and data. They're observables so i need to subscribe to access their values. My question is, how do i access them both together in a single subscribe?

```
this._route.params.subscribe(
  params => {
    getData(params['id'], data['id2'] <=== i need data value too. how do i get this???)
  });
```

Why does angular put them in 2 separate observables?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> how do i access them both together in a single subscribe?

You could use [`ActivatedRouteSnapshot`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html) from your  `ActivatedRoute`. `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` interface has `params` and `queryParams` property, and you could get the both value at the same time.

Don't try to inject `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` directly. It won't work. You must inject `ActivatedRoute` and access its `snapshot` property.

Note: We only get the initial value of the parameters with this technique

```
constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log(this._route.snapshot.params);
    console.log(this._route.snapshot.data);
}
```

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q0oxH4v3kZFTQw5XRduT?p=preview)

Another way, since `params` and `data` are `observable`, we could use [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip) operator to merge them, then access them in a single subscribe. But be aware that if one of `params` or `data` do not have value, then the subscribe will not be triggered.

```
this._route.params
  .zip(this._route.data)
  .subscribe((value) => {
    this.id = value[0]["id"]; // get param
    this.data = value[1]; // get data value
  });
```

Example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q0oxH4v3kZFTQw5XRduT?p=preview)

> Why does angular put them in 2 separate observables?

I have read the documentation, and you are correct,there are in separate observables, but I do not know why.

Comment: according to angular docs, they do. this._route.params.subscribe and this._route.data.subscribe

Comment: @Reynaldi yeah you were correct. I was wrong. Sorry, I should read the documentation more often.

Comment: Do we also need to unsubscribe from this subscription made, in ngOnDestroy() hook?

Answer (score 12):

Similar to Michael's response, you can use an `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` from your `ActivatedRoute` to get the route's `data`.

You can put this in a `params` subscription and it will be triggered even if the route does not contain any `params`.

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
  console.log(params);
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.data);
});
```

Comment: Note that `params` is a BehaviorSubject, so it keeps a value internally. Therefore subscribing will always immediately provides a value. (Yes this implementation could change but I doubt it)