# Angular ngIf router has /id ( /a dynamic number )

Tags: angular

I have created this in the main.ts which gets the route url:

```
router: string;

constructor(private _router: Router) { 
    this.router = _router.url; 
}
```

This works well. Then in the main.html:

```
<app-main-menu *ngIf="router == '/'"></app-main-menu>
<app-item-list *ngIf="router == '/list'"></app-item-list>

<app-item-info *ngIf="router == '/:id'"></app-item-info> <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK -->
```

When the route is `/2` or `/35` (or any number) I cannot get the app-item-info `ngIf` to work.

**My question is, how can I set the *ngIf to show (true) when I always have a string " / " with a dynamic number " 345 " ?**

Example:
When the URL (route is ): `localhost:4200/2` , the `ngIf` should display app-item-info.

EDIT: I cannot use `<router-outlet>` as I am using it for a different thing. Showing pages.

Comment: The problem is that you're comparing the `router` value with the string `'/:id'`, that's why it doesn't work. Also this approach looks like a very bad practice, try to refactor your code and use angular routing properly.

Comment: I agree with @igor_c. This does not seem to be the best approach. If you want to get the route parameters, you might want to look into  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560399/subscribing-to-route-params-and-data-in-angular-2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subscribing to route params and data in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560399/subscribing-to-route-params-and-data-in-angular-2)

Comment: Did you know that you can have multiple `<router-outlet>`s?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038001/multiple-named-router-outlet-angular-2

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use `<router-outlet>` to implement this functionality. Check out the official Angular documentation about the routing:
https://angular.io/guide/router

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/aqqyljyojye

Comment: I know this. But I'm using router-outlet for something else. I have to do it like this.

Comment: Then please update your post with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you?

```
<app-item-info *ngIf="isItemInfoRoute(router)"></app-item-info>
```

and in .ts

```
isItemInfoRoute(router: string) {
   return router.search(/^\/\d+/) > -1
}
```